# cypress, looping though visible elements, but getting asserts for hidden as well

Tags: cypress, ui-testing

I have a very strange situation when trying to test a filter selection on the page. I have a list of items and hiding some of them based on the selected filter. The hidden element has a forced style as "display: none", which should be treated to cypress as a non-visible element.

But I'm getting this hidden item checked and as a result my test failing.

I hope some of you came across similar issues and can help to understand what am I doing wrong.
(I have a suspicion it has something to do with when the element became hidden and cypress not picking up it properly). I'm very new cypress UI testing and UI testing overall.

This is a sample code:

```
cy.get(".row.uicomponent__devices-block .devices-item-wrapp:not(:hidden)")
    .should("have.length", 14)
    .each(function ($el, index, $list) {
        if ($el.is(":not(:hidden)")) {
            cy.get($el).should('have.attr', 'data-filter-brand', 'apple')
        }
    })
```

[image]

Comment: It is curious indeed that Cypress recogns the elements as visible. But I think you can do a work around by making sure the wished element doesn't has `display:none`. You could archive that by adding: ```js .should('not.have.css', 'display', `none`)```

Comment: I definitely will try, but since I'm doing this in the loop, is there any way I can get a conditional check of the element?